# error in doing changes in open stack horizon

Tags: python, django, compression, openstack, horizon

```
You have offline compression enabled but key "0a65c041a6b9d69baa764b57993373e8" is missing from offline manifest. You may need to run "python manage.py compress".
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://10.16.134.91/dashboard/admin/
Django Version: 1.8.17
Exception Type: OfflineGenerationError
Exception Value:
You have offline compression enabled but key "0a65c041a6b9d69baa764b57993373e8" is missing from offline manifest. You may need to run "python manage.py compress".
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compressor/templatetags/compress.py in render_offline, line 71
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:
['/opt/stack/horizon',
 '/opt/stack/keystone',
 '/opt/stack/swift',
 '/opt/stack/glance',
 '/opt/stack/neutron',
 '/opt/stack/nova',
 '/opt/stack/ironic',
 '/opt/stack/horizon',
 '/opt/stack/tempest',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/opt/stack/horizon/openstack_dashboard']
Server time: Thu, 9 Feb 2017 11:34:30 +0000
Error during template rendering
```

I made COMPREE_OFFLINE = False or I tried command python manage.py compress. Still I am getting errors.

Comment: I am trying to add html file

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).